# Functional approach to storing element counts in Map

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, imperative-programming

I came across a problem where I needed to count the number of Strings in an `Iterable` and store the sums in a `Map`. I came up with the following imperative solution:

```java
private static Map<String, Integer> generateCounts(Iterable<String> words) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<>();
    for (String word : words) {
        if (wordCounts.containsKey(word)) {
            Integer count = wordCounts.get(word);
            wordCounts.replace(word, count + 1);
        } else {
            wordCounts.put(word, 1);
        }
    }
    return wordCounts;
}
```

What would be a solution that leverages a functional approach instead of an imperative one like the one above?

Comment: `final Map<String, Integer> wordCount = StreamSupport.stream(words.spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), word -> 1, Integer::sum));` ([Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/F23pWL))

Answer (score 2):

If you are good with returning `Map<String, Long>` then you could do the below:

```java
StreamSupport.stream(words.spliterator(), false /*sequential*/)
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

OR, without using stream, you could do as:

```java
Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<>();
words.forEach(word -> wordCounts.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum));
return wordCounts;
```

Here the below `if-else` in your code is replaced by the `merge` function:

```java
if (wordCounts.containsKey(word)) {
    Integer count = wordCounts.get(word);
    wordCounts.replace(word, count + 1);
} else {
    wordCounts.put(word, 1);
}
```